# Shortname function not working properly

Tags: oracle, plsql

There is this code for generatig unique shortname from a table MMSTREPHDR . 
I have shortnames `kv`,`kv1`,`kv2`,`kv3` already in MMSTREPHDR . But on passing parameter kv it gives me `kv1`  and not `kv4`(since it's in LOOP) . Can't figure out what's wrong ?

```
FUNCTION FUN_GENERATE_SNAME (p_name VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  vl_sname   VARCHAR2 (15);
  n_cnt      NUMBER := 1;
  vl_sub     NUMBER;

  CURSOR c1 (vl_sname VARCHAR2)
  IS
     SELECT   a.repsname, a.repcode
       FROM   MMSTREPHDR a
      WHERE   TRIM (UPPER (a.repsname)) = TRIM (UPPER (vl_sname));
BEGIN
  vl_sname := TRIM (SUBSTR (p_name, 1, 15));

  FOR i IN c1 (vl_sname)
  LOOP
     vl_sub := LENGTH (TO_CHAR (n_cnt));
     vl_sname := SUBSTR (vl_sname, 1, (15 - vl_sub)) || n_cnt;
     n_cnt := n_cnt + 1;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN vl_sname;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS
  THEN
     RETURN vl_sname;
END fun_generate_sname;
```

Comment: Your loop runs only once. So, you are getting n_cnt as 1.

Comment: this comment alone was enough to answer my question .

Answer (score 1):

Your starting parameter is 'kv'.  This is what you pass to the cursor.  Consequently your cursor will select *one row* , the row where `MMSTREPHD.repsname = 'kv'`.

So your loop logic will be executed once.  So `cnt` = `.  Hence`vl_sname` becomes 'kv1', which is the value you get when the loop exits cleanly.

---

The cleanest way to fix this would be to admit that `MMSTREPHD.repsname` is a smart key, consisting of two elements: a subsystem name and a report number.  Splitting the column into two columns would make it a cinch to find the next report number for a given sub-system.  You can even retain the composite value as a virtual column (11g or later), or maintain it with triggers which sucks a bit.

Otherwise:

```
 select concat(p_name
             , trim(to_char(max(to_number(nvl(replace(repsname,p_name),'0')))+1)) )
 into vl_sname
 from MMSTREPHD
 where repsname like p_name||'%'
```

Caveat - I haven't tested this (yet) so ths brackets may not pair up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating the in below statement as

```
  vl_sname := SUBSTR (vl_sname, 1, (15 - vl_sub)) || n_cnt;
```

here n_cnt is given initial value to it as 1 in code above thats why its fetching you value as KV1.You should keep it null and after statement should increment it by 1 in loop. Hope will be usefull

Answer (score 0):

try this function

```
function FUN_GENERATE_SNAME(p_name varchar2) return varchar2 is
    l_idx     number;
    l_name_ln := length(trim(p_name));
begin
    select max(substr(trim(UPPER(a.repsname)), 1, -length(trim(UPPER(a.repsname)) + l_name_ln)) 
      into l_idx 
      from MMSTREPHDR a 
     where substr(trim(UPPER(a.repsname)), 1, l_name_ln) = trim(UPPER(vl_sname));

    if l_idx is null then
        -- mean name is unique
        return vl_sname;
    else
        return vl_sname ||(l_idx + 1);
    end if;
exception
    when others then
        return vl_sname;
end fun_generate_sname;
```